ASP.NET Core 8 - return JSON from EF result (column data as a property)
I have a SQL table for an application configuration that looks like this:



Key
Value




Configurarion1
True


Configurarion2
"C:\Temp"



And an ASP.NET Core 8 Web APIusing Entity Framework to return this table data as a JSON.
The problem is that by EF standards, the result is like this:
[
  {
    "Key": "Configurarion1",
    "Value": "True"
  },
  {
    "Key": "Configurarion2",
    "Value": "C:\Temp"
  } 
]

But I'd rather it looks like this (JSON pattern compatible):
[
  {
    "Configurarion1": True,
    "Configurarion2": "C:\Temp"
  } 
]

Is that possible without extensible workarounds?
Here is what I did in my code:
public class ConfigData
{
    public string? Key{ get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigEntityDto
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Key { get; set; } = "";

    [MaxLength(4000)]
    public string Value { get; set; } = "";
}

[HttpGet("/Configuration")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ConfigData>>> ReturnConfig()
{
    try
    {
        IQueryable<ConfigEntityDto> query = context.ConfigDb;

        var result = await query.ToListAsync();

        if (result == null || result.Count == 0)
            return NoContent();

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}

Thanks!

The question is unclear. EF doesn't produce JSON. There's no "EF pattern" or "JSON pattern" either. EF doesn't even deal with tables, it works with application entities that have whatever shape you need. In ASP.NET Core, configuration settings are loaded by the Configuration middleware and it is possible to create a configuration source that loads settings from a database. No JSON is involved at any stage

The custom Configuration provider article in the .NET Core docs shows how to read settings from a key/value table and use them just like any other settings.

On the other hand, if you want to treat that data as objects, you have a serious problem. The table design is a well know bad practice. Value is a string, not a boolean or number. You can't just pivot rows into columns, you'd have to parse the values to produce numbers or booleans. If you're OK with producing just strings, you can use results.ToDictionary(r=>r.Key,r.Value) to produce a Dictionary<string,string>.

Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos! The problem is that is a legacy table that I can't change... I'lll try to use the dictionary like this... it's ok to produce only string....

Returning a Dictionary<string, string> should work, but be aware that dictionary keys cannot be null.  And even if they could, JSON property names cannot be null.  Your Key property is declared as nullable: string? Key, so you will need to handle null keys somehow.

@PanagiotisKanavos, it works! thanks a lot!

@dbc, yep! it's market as nullable but I've selected only ones that's not null/empty... it's hard do exist some Key null btw.... thanks!

You could try this below code to transform the JSON response into the format you could like to achive.
To convert the the list of ConfigEntityDto objects into a dictionary where the key is the Key property and the value is the Value property.then we create a dynamic object (ExpandoObject) and add each key-value pair from the dictionary as properties of this dynamic object.Transformed object is returned as a single-item list to match your desired JSON format.
ConfigurationController.cs:
using ConfigApi.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ConfigApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class ConfigurationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ConfigDbContext _context;

        public ConfigurationController(ConfigDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetConfigurations()
        {
            try
            {
                var configurations = await _context.Configurations.ToListAsync();

                if (configurations == null || configurations.Count == 0)
                    return NoContent();

                // Transform to JSON format
                var configDictionary = configurations.ToDictionary(
                    item => item.Key,
                    item => (object)item.Value == "True" || item.Value == "False" ? (object)bool.Parse(item.Value) : item.Value
                );

                var configObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
                foreach (var kvp in configDictionary)
                {
                    configObject[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                }

                return Ok(new List<object> { configObject });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Error retrieving data from the database");
            }
        }

    }
}

ConfigDbContext.cs:
using ConfigApi.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConfigApi.Data
{
    public class ConfigDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ConfigDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ConfigEntityDto> Configurations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ConfigEntityDto>()
                .HasKey(e => e.Key);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ConfigEntityDto>()
                .Property(e => e.Value)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(4000);
        }

    }
}

ConfigEntityDto.cs;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ConfigApi.Models
{
    public class ConfigEntityDto
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Key { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [MaxLength(4000)]
        public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    }
}


